# document.createElement("LABEL")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to create an Input field.</p>

  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var y = document.createElement("LABEL");
      var yv = prompt("Enter Caption value:", "");
      y.setAttribute("value", yv);
      document.body.appendChild(y);

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to create 'lebel' using the above code. it's not working. plz help...

Comment: Label does not have a attribute `value`. Use `y.textContent = yv`

Comment: If you use your browser's debugging tools and view the HTML on the page, you'll find that your code *does* in fact successfully create a `<label>` element, with a `value` attribute, and add it to the page.  That `<label>` element has no content, so it has nothing to display.

Answer (score 5):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.createElement("LABEL");
  var yv = prompt("Enter Caption value:", "");
  y.innerHTML = yv;
  document.body.appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create an Input field.</p>

<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to add content.

Comment: Please note that it is a bad practice to answer a duplicate. You should rather use your vote and close it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a simple thing myfriend, put someting inside the created label like in the snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to create an Input field.</p>

  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var y = document.createElement("label");
      var yv = prompt("Enter Caption value:", "");
      y.setAttribute("value", yv);
      y.innerText = yv;
      document.body.appendChild(y);

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why does your generated label tag have a `value` attribute?

Comment: good question, I just edited the question's snippet, maybe it's used for some non-question related feature?